# Loading cross domain SVG using jQuery SVG plugin

Tags: jquery, svg, amazon-s3

I have a code loading SVG waveforms like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < waveforms.length; i++) {
  $('#player-progress-' + i).svg({loadURL:waveforms[i]});
};
```

It works fine when the SVG are in the same server as the code, but when I moved the SVGs to Amazon S3 it stops working.

The SVGs are in the right bucket and folder, the URL's in the waveforms array are fine, but they don't load.

- A cross-domain issue?
- Is there a work around or fix for this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable CORS on S3. According to [this article](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-cross-origin-resource-sharing/) there is a an Add CORS Configuration option in the property page for each bucket.

Comment: Added this but still doesn't work. Do I need to refresh the CDN or something?